# without trigger script starts addeventListener

Tags: addeventlistener

What am I doing wrong? I don't want this to trigger until I click the text.

```
window.onload = eventMonitor;
```

html:

```
<div id="textBox">
<a id="mousee" href="#">Hidden Ships</a></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function eventMonitor(){
    document.getElementById('mousee').addEventListener('click', shipsSlider(), false);

    function shipsSlider(){
        slideWindow = window.open("shipslide.html")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what am I doing wrong?

you're calling the `shipsSlider` function in `window.onload`...

```
document.
getElementById('mousee').
addEventListener(
  'click',
  shipsSlider(), // <- right here
  false
)
```

drop the parentheses.  there's a difference between a function and whatever it returns.

Comment: nothing in your browser's javascript console?  how about adding some debugging statements into your code, like `console.log("got here")`.  it's really trivial to see how far it gets and how it fails, but you need to *look*.

Comment: that's exactly what I did, and figured it out! great idea!